# Google Analytics push trackevent in knockout.js data-binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, google-analytics

I'm trying to push a trackevent on clicking on a link but somehow this event seems not to be fired as it doe not show up in analytics dashboard.

heres the relevant anchor tag

```
<a target="_blank" data-bind="attr:{href: 'http://www.xyz.de/profile/id/'+id()},click:function(){_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search', 'GoTo Homepage', 'Profile',slug]);}">
```

has anybody an idea ?

for any help **thanks** in advance

update :

i tryed to prevent the default behaviour on klicking the link and after push event set window location to url, but that also is not working

like :

```
data-bind="attr:{href: 'http://www.xyz.de/profile/id/'+id()},click:function(){return false;_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search', 'GoTo Homepage', 'Profile',slug]);window.location = 'http://www.xyz.de/profile/id/'+id();}"
```

am i on the right path ?

Comment: it's the name of the profile, the anchor tag is inside a ko-foreach and is a property of the objects in observableArray i'm iterating over.So this should have nothing todo, my latest guess is, that the page changes before push event executes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom binding, I have found this to be useful.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.gaEvent = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var gaObj = (typeof value === 'object' && !(value instanceof Array));
            if (gaObj) {
                var evt = value.event;
                if (evt.category != undefined);
                    ga('send', 'event', evt.category, evt.action != undefined ? evt.action : '', evt.label != undefined ? evt.label : '');
            }                
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    }
};
```

And you can apply the data-bind something like this

```
div class="module" data-bind="gaEvent: { event: { category: 'Traffic', action:'Manage'} }"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are just trying to handle a click event, do something, and then change the window.location -

Register a click binding handler on your anchor tag -

```
<a data-bind="click: trackEvent">
```

Then in your view model -

```
function trackEvent() {
    // Not sure what you are doing here but copied it in as-was
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search', 'GoTo Homepage', 'Profile',slug]);
    gotoHomePage();
}

function gotoHomePage() {
    var newUrl = 'http://www.xyz.de/profile/id/' + id();
    window.location.href = newUrl;
    return true; // Not sure if you are using promises anywhere
}
```